# How to add a snippet of category, used in a different snippet

Tags: wagtail

How do I have a snippet of category be used in another snippet called resource? I want to have a list of Resources filtered by category and category is a snippet of its own. I'm getting this error when I try to create a Resource:

```
AttributeError at /admin/snippets/home/resource/add/
'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'rel'
```

Here is my code:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    """Snippet for Resources"""

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    info = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ResourceCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel("resource_name"),
                FieldPanel("phone_number"),
            ],
            heading="Resource information"
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('website')
            ],
            heading="Links"
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('info')
            ],
            heading="Info"
        ),
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel("category", label="Category")
            ]
        )
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation of this class"""
        return self.resource_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Resource"
        verbose_name_plural = "Resources"

register_snippet(Resource)

class ResourceCategory(models.Model):
    """Snippet for Resources"""

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                FieldPanel('category_name')
            ],
            heading="Category"
        )
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        """String representation of this class"""
        return self.category_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

register_snippet(ResourceCategory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `category` field should use `FieldPanel('category')`, not `InlinePanel`. InlinePanel is for managing multiple child objects belonging to the snippet, but here a Resource only belongs to a single ResourceCategory.

(If you do intend to allow a resource to belong to multiple categories, you'll need to adjust your models so that Resource has a child model, containing a `ParentalKey` to Resource and a `ForeignKey` to ResourceCategory.)

Comment: I tried the first and it worked @gasman. However, when I do the second, I'm getting issues. home.ResourceCatsOrderable.resource: (modelcluster.E001) ParentalKey must point to a subclass of ClusterableModel.

Comment: `from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel`, then update Resource to inherit from `ClusterableModel` rather than `models.Model` - see https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster for more details. (Also, you probably want the `related_name` on the ParentalKey to be `categories`, as that's what allows you to access `resource.categories.all()`.)